# Language model with grammar for Pocketsphinx

Tags: ros, pocketsphinx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Does anyone know if there's a way to include grammar in the language model for Pocketsphinx? Either by using a jsgf-file or something else.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49559/language-model-with-grammar-for-pocketsphinx/) by [Kinna](https://answers.ros.org/users/3228/kinna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2012-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Pocketsphinx ROS package is based on gstreamer's pocketsphinx plugin. As far as I know, this does not accept the jsgf-files. This question has come up a few times, but as far as I know, nobody has found a way to make it work.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2012-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2